# Container connecting to SQL container database error

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm practicing a simple application using Kubernetes. I have created a Mysql deployment and a service and it's up and running, but when the application container that uses MySQL database tries to connect to the database, it crashes with SQL connection error as  below

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'10.1.0.49' (using password: YES)

It looks like the MySQL databases do not allow connection from the container IP address. How do you allow the connection to the Mysql database from any application server IP address as the IP always changes in Kubernetes world? Or the issue is related to something else? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does the database accept access from IPs other than 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yes. I fixed the issue somehow by inject the password as a secret. It could albe a typo, couldn't tell you which one of them has fixed. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by injecting the password as secret.